# Is there a tool that detects this usage of a nil interface that results in runtime crash?

Tags: go, interface, compilation, runtime-error, detect

The following code causes a SIGSEGV error. Are there tools such as linters that can flag this bad logic?

```
package main

// Person is ...
type Person interface {
        M()
}

func main() {
        var i Person
        i.M()
}
```

golint does not detect this.

Comment: Can you share what part of this you consider to be an invalid use? Is it the ability to call the method `M` on a nil `Person`?

Comment: It's "documented" in [the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/13) :-P

Comment: I, for one, have no idea except for vague feeling that the devs prefer "all or nothing" approach. What I mean is that while in _this_ case the analyzis does indeed appear sufficiently easy to implement, what about the following — `var i Person; i = &SomeTypeWithMethodM{}; /* 100 lines of code */ i = nil; /* 100 lines of code */ i.M()`? It could be possible to implement in mostly the same style as escape analysis: have a complexity threshold after which the compiler gives up. But that could mean it would flag as errors only _trivial_ cases (such as yours), …

Comment: … and non-trivial cases would not produce any error, essentially creating in a programmer a false sense of confidence. But this is different from a failure to completely trace a variable's lifetime during esacpe analysis: if the latter fails, the compiler pessimistically generates less-than-optimal code, _which is still correct_ according to the spec, just less effective.

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham, by "obviously bad use," I meant "obviously bad logic." I'd thought it's obvious that "i" is *nil* value here.

Comment: @kostix, nil pointer is a notorious source of run-time errors, and thus, I'd hope, the Go tooling would try to help whenever possible.

Comment: @AcBap Does _any_ other language detect NPE at compile time?

Comment: @Iblisto, I'm not aware of any!  As I indicated in your other comment that this could be a "feature" request. Since Go eliminates memory leak problem, I was a bit disappointed that this issue occurs, and thus wanted to learn more about it. At the same time, I was also looking for the tools that could help.

Answer (score 1):

Because compiler doesn't have knowledge of what the underlying concrete type `i` has at compile time. Consider this example:

```golang
func main() {
        var i Person
        if gender == "woman" {
                i = &Woman{}
        }
        i.M()
}
```

Because compiler doesn't know the value of `gender` at compile time, it also doesn't know whether `&Woman{}` is assigned to `i` or is left as a zero value of `Person` interface, which is `nil`.

Comment: The OP had presented a specifically trivial case which is — ostensibly — easy to detect.

Comment: @kostix I see your point. Well it's just not part of compiler's job - sounds more like you're asking for a "feature request" to the compiler here. This applies to any languages, not just Go. That said, I'm sure there are linters that _warn_ you for the code that can possibly produce NullPointerException in some languages.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t an invalid use. The variable `i` is bound to an interface `Person` whose value is nil.

Accessing a field or calling a method on a nil interface value will result in a panic, as observed.

Comment: This _is_ relevant: if the underlying type wasn't `nil`, it would be OK to perform the call as the implementation of `M` of that type could gracefully deal with `nil` receiver value.